# CSS: alignment between local host and server changing

Tags: css

I'm making a webpage that has rotating background images. Developing on localhost, I arranged things such that the people in the images are positioned where I want them to be. However, when I pushed to the server and opened the webpage in different browsers, some of the people are off the screen, and the results vary per browser.

this is the CSS I'm using

```
.animate-this .img1,
.animate-this .img3 {
    clear: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1210px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
.animate-this .img2 {
    clear: left;
    display: block;
    width: 1620px;
    height: 1210px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #2b292b;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

.animate-this .img4 {
    clear: left;
    display: block;
    width: 1522px;
    height: 1210px;
    background-color: #2b292b;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

Comment: Please attach your html.

Comment: Run a diff on your server CSS and your local CSS. Also check your deployed background images are the same as your local version. It is most likely some fault in your deploy method.

Comment: @Rain do you know Ruby on Rails? hard to show the html without posting from different files, and the problem is also that background image is changing with javascript. However, you can look at the app on the server at sugarpova.herokuapp.com

Comment: @Duopixel how do I do that? Can you explain a little more?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the link provided by you. I think the below CSS might be helpful.

```
.animate-this .img1,
.animate-this .img3 {
    clear: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1210px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
.animate-this .img2 {
    clear: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1210px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #2b292b;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

.animate-this .img4 {
    clear: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1210px;
    background-color: #2b292b;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

Also I noticed one thing in your page. With each scroll it adds 3-4 images in you page which are already in your page. This will make the page heavy as these are very big images.  So please see if you can scroll the images without adding them to the page repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks, but if I make the page scroll the images won't switch automatically, and since the page is adding the same images, it's not making it heavier because the images should be cached, shouldn't they?

Comment: I am not sure how Cache works in  Ruby on Rails. I know how this works in .NET. Normally for each image browser sends a request to server separately.